Hausdorff measure and orthogonal projection
I was reading Federer's proof of Gustin's boxing inequality and during the proof there's a step which is unclear to me. Here's the context: $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ compacts sets such that $A\cup B$ is convex and $\mathrm{diam} A\cup B=1$, and $p_{z}$ denotes the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ onto the orthogonal complement of $z\in\mathbb{R}^{n}-\{0\}$. At the end of the proof he writes ($\mathscr{L}^{n}$ and $\mathscr{H}^{s}$ mean Lebesgue and Hausdorff measures) $$ \int_{|z|\leq 1}\mathscr{L}^{n}(\{x : \, x\in A \, \text{and} \, x+z\in B\}) \, d\mathscr{L}^{n}(z)\leq \int_{|z|\leq 1}\mathscr{H}^{n-1}(p_{z}(A\cap B)) \, d\mathscr{L}^{n}(z) \,.$$ I sketched some pictures to convince myself of this inequality, yet I could not verify it. Any help would be appreciated.
